# What is the word for the concept of present, past and future?

Tags: terminology

I like this explanation from Wikipedia:

> Thus tense refers to *temporally when* while aspect refers to *temporally how*.
>   (Wikipedia | Grammatical Aspect | [Modern Usage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_aspect#Modern_usage))

But normally dictionaries say *tense* is 'forms' as:

> **[tense](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/tense_2)** (*grammar*) any of the *forms* of a verb that may be used to show the time of the action or state expressed by the verb
>   (Learner's OED)

If it's about forms, then how do you call the concept of the present, past, and future, itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of past, present and future is known as **time**.

The fact that verbs can be inflected to mark past, present and (in some languages) future is called **tense**.

There are three main ways of defining "tense" as it relates to English.

**1.** Many traditional grammars list a large number of tenses: the simple present (or present simple), the present progressive (or present continuous), the present perfect (or perfect), the present perfect progressive, the simple past (or preterite or preterit or past simple or past indefinite), the past progressive, the past perfect (or pluperfect), the past perfect progressive, the simple future, the future continuous, the future perfect, and the future perfect continuous.  Some grammars also use the word "tense" for the present conditional and the perfect conditional.

**2.** Most modern grammarians distinguish two tenses in English, present and past.  The progressive and the perfect are called *aspect* instead.  Thus, the past perfect is a combination of the past tense and the perfect aspect.

**3.** Huddleston and Pullum use the term "primary tense" for the present/past distinction, the term "secondary tense" for the perfect/non-perfect distinction, and the term "aspect" for the progressive/non-progressive distinction.

Answer (score 0):

It's no different that the answer already given is very helpful to me, but I've just found that Random House Unabridged Dictionary of American English © 2017
tells us *additional* meanings of 'tense' as follows:

> [**tense** 2](http://www.wordreference.com/definition/tense)
>   *n*.
>   3. the time, as past, present, or future, expressed by such a category.
>   4. such categories or constructions, or their meanings collectively.

However, dictionaries for learner's nor the dictionary in my native language that I've seen so far don't say it.

It might not very much in English, but I've been feeling when I'm writing about grammar in my native language that it's inconvenient if we can't use 'tense' to refer to the concept of time like present, past, or future, itself.